# Custom ViewCellRenderer in iOS does not work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use a custom ViewCellRenderer for iOS in Xamarin Forms, but the renderer never called. I'm using a custom ListViewRenderer too and that is working like a charm. Anyone have any idea about this?

Here is my TableViewRenderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(CustomTableViewRenderer))]
namespace OdontoWayPaciente.Mobile.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomTableViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.TableFooterView = new UIView(CGRect.Empty);


                if (e.NewElement.IsGroupingEnabled)
                {
                    var groupedTableView = new UITableView(Control.Frame, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
                    groupedTableView.Source = Control.Source;

                    SetNativeControl(groupedTableView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewCellRenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(CustomAllViewCellRendereriOS))]
namespace OdontoWayPaciente.Mobile.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomAllViewCellRendereriOS : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tableView)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tableView);

            if (cell != null)
            {
                cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            }

            if (tableView.Style == UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
            {
                cell.TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
                cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            }


            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewCell XAML code:

```
 <ViewCell Height="{StaticResource listItem_alturaLinhaUnica}"
          StyleId="disclosure">
    <ContentView>
        <ContentView.BackgroundColor>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="White"/>
        </ContentView.BackgroundColor>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding TextoAcesso}" 
                Style="{DynamicResource TextoPrimario}">
                <Label.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="18, 8, 0, 8"/>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Label.Margin>
            </Label>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about defining a XAML layout for a view that you're then using a custom renderer on.. can I see the code where you're actually using your custom cell?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, but I did many testes here and verified that, if I use ListView with GroupingEnabled=True, CustomViewRenderer is not called, but GroupingEnabled=false, CustomViewCellRenderer is called

Answer (score 1):

Please check your ListView's `ItemsSource`, the `ListView` should have at least one cell then the CustomViewRenderer will be called.

> if I use ListView with GroupingEnabled=True, CustomViewRenderer is not
>   called, but GroupingEnabled=false, CustomViewCellRenderer is called

Whether you just add some groups in your `ItemsSource` like: `new List<Group> { group1, group2 };`, but each group contains none item. When you set the `IsGroupingEnabled` to false, the ListView has two cells in this case so renderer called. But if the `IsGroupingEnabled` is true, the ListView just has two sections without any cells then renderer will not be called.

Comment: You can try to add some items(model) in each group you want to show. You can refer to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17976/listview-grouping-example-please) for how to create a grouped listView.